# Multiple POST request handling concurrently in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, concurrency, tornado

I have a tornado server listening to port 6789 for POST requests on `"/train"` and `"/predict"`. train method might take upto 3 hrs to complete, while predict might return in 2 minutes. I want them to be handled concurrently. So even when "/train" is running, if a POST request for "/predict" arrives, it can handle that concurrently and return its output without waiting for "/train" to complete.

I have tried using `ThreadPool` but it still doesn't run concurrently.

My present code is as follows. It functions but if request to train is made and then request to predict is made. It waits for train to complete before handling predict. Assume train and predict functions are present and don't take any parameters.

```
import logging
import time
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import flask
from tornado import wsgi, httpserver, ioloop
from flask import Flask
from train_script import train
from predict_script import predict
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/train", methods=['POST'])
def train_run():
    payload = flask.request.get_json(silent=True)
    if payload is not None:
        try:
            async_result = pool.apply_async(train)
            response = async_result.get() 
            resp = flask.jsonify(response)
            resp.status_code = 200
        except Exception as ex:
            resp = flask.jsonify({"status": "Failure"})
            resp.status_code = 500
    else:
        resp = flask.jsonify({"status": "Failure"})
        resp.status_code = 500
    return resp

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict_run():
    payload = flask.request.get_json(silent=True)
    if payload is not None:
        try:
            async_result = pool.apply_async(predict)
            response = async_result.get() 
            resp = flask.jsonify(response)
            resp.status_code = 200
        except Exception as ex:
            resp = flask.jsonify({"status": "Failure"})
            resp.status_code = 500
    else:

        resp = flask.jsonify({"status": "Failure"})
        resp.status_code = 500
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 6789
    http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(wsgi.WSGIContainer(app))
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)# Expects max concurrent requests to be 10
    http_server.listen(port)
    logging.info("Tornado server starting on port {}".format(port))
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a background job? Yes, it will complicate your setup a bit, but on the other hand will allow you to easily handle the long-running jobs and queue them properly.

Comment: No, I can use background job too. But how to go about it?

Comment: It's a bit long topic for SO comment or answer, but here are few links to go: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/

Answer (score 0):

Tornado's [`WSGIContainer`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer) does not support any kind of concurrency. Either use Tornado's RequestHandler interfaces without Flask or WSGI, or use Flask with `gunicorn` or `uwsgi`. You gain almost nothing and lose a lot by combining Tornado with WSGI frameworks, so this is only useful in certain specialized situations.